# Add Dynamic Text to images using GD Library or any other plugin in PHP

Tags: php, image-processing, gd

I want to make an app where user can see their meaning of name. I am done with the php part its just I am stuck how to output it to good looking image. I have used PHP image magician library before. But I am still not able to get it in the format I wanted.

Any help will be useful.

CHECK the image format below

https://fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/safe_image.php?d=AQDPCj8lZUELWsXD&w=470&h=246&url=http%3A%2F%2Fs3.alegra.me%2Fname%2Fnombre.php%3Fnombre%3Djayanta&cfs=1&upscale

Comment: I havent coded that part yet for image manipulation.. I need the logic from you guys..

Comment: What logic do you need though?

Comment: since using GD library i have to pinpoint the location of starting text, how can I make it dynamic and good looking fonts.. just like the image I have attached in my question.. Also I think I need to fix the Image size first.. but what if the name has more than 10 characters I need to adjust that too.

Answer (score 0):

```
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg('xc7ci4ptuxmgy3nd0brz.jpg');
$font="tahoma.ttf";

$red = imagecolorallocate($im, 255,0,0);
$string="JAYANTA";

$last_string= substr( $string, 1 );
$temp_x = 105;

$down_string[0]="JUST";
$down_string[1]="AMUSING";
$down_string[2]="YOUNG";        
$down_string[3]="AMUSING";
$down_string[4]="NICE"; 
$down_string[5]="TOUGH";    
$down_string[6]="AMUSING";

$bbox =  imagefttext($im, 80, 0,90, 190, $red, $font, $string);
$temp_y=205;  //y cord. of $down_string 

for($x=1;$x < count($down_string);$x++){

    for($y=0;$y < count($down_string);$y++){

       $bbox =  imagefttext($im, 12, 0, $temp_x, $temp_y, $red, $font, $down_string[$y][$x]);
          $temp_x += 56+$y*1.8;
    }   
    $temp_x =  105;
    $temp_y+=15;
}

header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

[image]

As you can see, ther is a lot of problems, but the solution is in the [imagefttext](http://php.net//manual/en/function.imagefttext.php) function.